# The counter in my while loop is not working properly

Tags: python

I'm working on a primitive number guessing game. Here's my code:

```
number = 68
counter=0
limit=3
guess = input("Guess the number from 1 to 100:")

while counter < limit:
    if int(guess) != number:
        counter+=1
        if int(guess) < number:
            guess = input("Too low, try again:")
        if int(guess) > number: 
            guess = input("Too high, try again:")
    if int(guess) == number:
        print("You won!")
        break
```

It keeps asking for my input for more than 3 times, and the program doesn't stop working until I put in a lower number 3 times and vice versa. How do I solve it?

Comment: The counter is not seperate for greater or less than, its unclear what you're asking

Comment: You need to use `elif`. If you enter number lower than `number`, script will ask for input and immediately checks `guess` in same iteration.

Comment: I already work on this kind before, check it out [here](https://github.com/comsavvy/Guessing_game/blob/master/guessing_game.py)

Comment: Side note, instead of repeating `int(guess)` everywhere, just convert it once: `guess = int(input(...))`

Answer (score 3):

```
if int(guess) < number:
    guess = input("Too low, try again:")
if int(guess) > number: 
    guess = input("Too high, try again:")
```

This is problematic, as you take an input and then re-check the new input/number. This should be an if/else statement.

Answer (score 3):

```
number = 68
counter=0
limit=3
guess = input("Guess the number from 1 to 100: ")

while counter < limit:
    if int(guess) != number:
        counter += 1
        if int(guess) < number:
            guess = input("Too low, try again:")
        else:
            guess = input("Too high, try again:")
    if int(guess) == number:
        print("You won!")
        break
```

You can see that the `if` statement has been turned into an `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the second possibilities that cannot happen at the same time with "elif" commands.In the first if part, you take 2 predictions and increase the counter 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned before the problem is with your if condition, but I would optimize it further:

```
number = 68 
counter = 0 
limit = 3 
input_message = "Guess the number from 1 to 100: "
final_message = "You lost"  
while counter < limit:
    guess = int(input(input_message))
    if guess == number:
        final_message = "You won!" 
        break     
    if guess < number:
        input_message = "Too low. Try again: " 
    else:
        input_message = "Too high. Try again: "     
    counter += 1 
print(final_message)
```